# Alamofire upload crashing only on iphone 6s plus

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire

My app uploads photos perfectly with alamofire 4.0.1 on all devices except iphone 6s plus.(tested on iphone 4s,5,5s,6,7,7plus with versions 9.2 and 10.1)

```
        let image = profileimage
        Alamofire.upload( multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                // import image to request
                if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 1) {

                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "user_profile.profile_picture", fileName: "profile_picture"+NSUUID().uuidString, mimeType: "image/png")
                }      
            },
            usingThreshold: SessionManager.multipartFormDataEncodingMemoryThreshold,
            to:  baseURL+String(currentUser.id)+"/",
            method: .put,
            headers: headers,
            encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        let user = createUserFromJSON(response.result.value as! NSDictionary) //crashes here, response is nil
                        completion(user, nil)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    let error = encodingError
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
        })
```

On iphone 6s plus it crashes with this:

```
2016-12-02 13:26:04.391264 app[22207:366529] [] nw_socket_get_input_frames recvmsg(fd 14, 1024 bytes): [54] Connection reset by peer
2016-12-02 13:26:04.393678 app[22207:366529] [] nw_endpoint_flow_prepare_output_frames [3.1 52.17.90.251:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Failed to use 1 frames, marking as failed
2016-12-02 13:26:04.394564 app[22207:366529] [] nw_socket_write_close shutdown(14, SHUT_WR): [57] Socket is not connected
2016-12-02 13:26:04.394945 app[22207:366529] [] nw_endpoint_flow_service_writes [3.1 52.17.90.251:443 ready socket-flow (satisfied)] Write request has 0 frame count, 0 byte count
2016-12-02 13:26:04.396875 app[22207:366613] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [89] Operation canceled
```

Comment: Which ios version in iPhone 6 plus?

Comment: It crashes on IOS version 10.1 and 9.2

Comment: You have tested your app for all those devices, meanining you are using iPhone Simulator or actual devices?  And how big is a typical image?

Comment: Mostly with simulator indeed! Tested with devices: iphone 6, 7 and 5s. The crash was first found on 6s plus device, but also occurred on 6s plus simulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This had nothing to do with Alamofire! It was NGINX which had a maximum file upload size. I found out by printing the responseString instead of JSON. It said "Request entity too large".

```
          upload.responseString { response in
             print(response.result.value)
            }
```